# How to convert HAR formatted request to Powershell request?

Tags: powershell, http, har

I have this simple request which is in the format of [HAR](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/har-12-spec/#request)

```json
{
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "https://example.com",
    "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
    "cookies": [],
    "headers": [],
    "queryString": [],
    "postData": {
        "mimeType": ""
    },
    "headersSize": 0,
    "bodySize": 0
}
```

I need to convert this request to Powershell (WebRequest/RestMethod)

Any help is appreciated!!

I tried using [Httpsnippet](https://github.com/Kong/httpsnippet/). It works fine for simple requests but for some reason it fails converting complex requests.

Comment: The sample document you've shown looks pretty simple - does `httpsnippet` fail to convert it to PowerShell? If so, how? Errors occurring? Incomplete output? If not, please share a sample document for which conversion to PowerShell actually fails.

Comment: Hey @MathiasR.Jessen I created an issue for the same where I mentioned some more details. Here is the link https://github.com/Kong/httpsnippet/issues/341#issue-2131520753